# How are conflicting properties resolved if multiple profiles are activated

Tags: java, maven, build

[Maven profiles documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) does not mention this, and it is probably a sign of bad build process design, but are there rules for resolving conflicting properties if multiple profiles are active and they all define the same property?

Im quite sure that local declaration (in the `pom.xml`) would override the declaration in the `settings.xml`, not so sure for colocal profiles

- is the declaration order inside the file important?
- is there a defined activation order that may be important?
- is the order important, if activated manually over CLI (`-Pprofile1,profile2`)?

Thank you

Comment: Check http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4946 and related issues

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov - Thanks - an interesting and informative read, though quite scattered. I hope I'll be able to put the bits together and figure it out for the most relevant cases and answer on my own. Looks like there is no real guidance out there yet. In case you have compiled something sensible out of the issues alreeady, I'd appreciate an answer ;)

Comment: Tip: Use `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: @noahz Thanks, I thought about that, but we don't have the help plugin in the internal repo and it could take several weeks to get it from procurement :( will have to try that at home

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no resolving conflicts happening - only overriding. Afaik the order is settings, pom, and then command line. For multiple profiles in a pom and settings file the order in the file matters as well and beyond that things are different depending on Maven version.

I would strongly suggest to reduce your usage of profiles so that you do NOT have to worry about these complexities and certainly get the help plugin installed.

Also you can see the effective pom within Eclipse in the M2Eclipse plugin in the POM editor. That should help you in the mean time.

And answer to your questions:

Yes

Yes

Yes

All orders matter and can result in, lets just say "surprising" results sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Manfred. As I supposed, it sometimes boils down to the "try it and see" approach.

Comment: The problem with that is that you try and see on one Maven version and it works differently on another. Try to reduce profile usage as much as you can..