# How are non-conflicting configurations resolved if multiple profiles are activated?

Tags: maven

Following up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12477562/2249614) question:
I can't find information on how the union of multiple (active) maven profiles is built, under the condition that they are *not* conflicting.

Consider the following example:
I want to control how my test cases are run with maven-surefire-plugin. First I need to configure two different environments (jenkins-CI-server) and local. Second I want to enable running different sets of tests.
I would have four profiles:

1. `env_jenkins` for running on jenkins
2. `env_local` for running on local
3. `testset_A` for running some tests
4. `testset_B` for running some other tests

Note that for all those profiles I need to define the plugin configuration for the maven-surefire-plugin.
(See below for the concrete xml-configuration)

Then I would like to combine the profiles to run - for example - testset A on jenkins.

My questions:

- Is such a behaviour supported by maven?
- On which stage does the overriding mentioned in [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12477562/2249614) occur? Is the entire plugin configuration overridden (-> my example would not work). Or only really conflicting parts (-> my example would work)?
- Does the overriding behaviour depend on the plugin or is it consistent among all maven plugins?

Example pom:

```
<profiles>
    <!-- handle system configurations (e.g. one for jenkins environment, one for local) -->
    <profile>
        <id>env_jenkins</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <arquillian.launch>jbossas-managed</arquillian.launch>
                            <jbossHttpPortOverride>8080</jbossHttpPortOverride>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>env_local</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <arquillian.launch>jbossas-managed-jenkins</arquillian.launch>
                                <jbossHttpPortOverride>${jboss.http.port}</jbossHttpPortOverride>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <!-- define different test sets -->
    <profile>
        <id>testset_A</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>TestA1.java</include>
                            <include>TestA2.java</include>
                            <include>TestA3.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>testset_B</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>TestB1.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Regardless of what actually happens, why are you trying to do this? This probably could be solved with no profile at all. Look at [`includesFile`](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includesFile) to specify the includes dynamically, for example. Then you can define only two properties for `jbossHttpPortOverride` and `arquillian.launch`, maybe in a profile.

Comment: @Tunaki: thanks for the suggestions for this specific example. However the general problem is a part of maven I don't understand since long. So I will keep the question opened.

Comment: What I expect, is that configuration are inherited between profiles, and in case of duplicate properties, the last one declared in the POM wins. This may change with a parent/child process because you can declare a plugin `<inherited>false</inherited>` so that child do not inherit parent configuration.

Comment: you can check the resulting effective-pom by using "help:effective-pom -PprofileA,profileB" choose the profile combination you need and the effective-pom will show you how the end result look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works using the same [inheritance/merging process](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) that works between parent and children POMs. Using the Maven help plugin can confirm this (using Maven 3.3.9):

1. Order of profile declarations in the POM matters. A plugin configuration inherits the same plugin's configuration declared in an active profile appearing before it in the POM.
2. The attributes `combine.self` and `combine.children` can be used to control the merging.

---

**Example with default settings (without using `combine.self` or `combine.children`, i.e. with `combine.children="merge"` implicitly):**

> ```
> mvn help:effective-pom -Penv_local,testset_A
> ```

Effective POM shows merged configurations:

```
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>TestA1.java</include>
            <include>TestA2.java</include>
            <include>TestA3.java</include>
          </includes>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <arquillian.launch>jbossas-managed-jenkins</arquillian.launch>
            <jbossHttpPortOverride>${jboss.http.port}</jbossHttpPortOverride>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>TestA1.java</include>
        <include>TestA2.java</include>
        <include>TestA3.java</include>
      </includes>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <arquillian.launch>jbossas-managed-jenkins</arquillian.launch>
        <jbossHttpPortOverride>${jboss.http.port}</jbossHttpPortOverride>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
```

---

**Example with `combine.self="override"`:**

```
<profile>
    <id>testset_A</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration combine.self="override">
                    <includes>
                        <include>TestA1.java</include>
                        <include>TestA2.java</include>
                        <include>TestA3.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

> ```
> mvn help:effective-pom -Penv_local,testset_A
> ```

Effective POM shows only `testset_A`'s configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration combine.self="override">
          <includes>
            <include>TestA1.java</include>
            <include>TestA2.java</include>
            <include>TestA3.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration combine.self="override">
      <includes>
        <include>TestA1.java</include>
        <include>TestA2.java</include>
        <include>TestA3.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

---

**Example with `combine.children="append"`:**

```
<profile>
    <id>testset_A</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration combine.children="append">
                    <includes>
                        <include>TestA1.java</include>
                        <include>TestA2.java</include>
                        <include>TestA3.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

> ```
> mvn help:effective-pom -Penv_local,testset_A
> ```

Effective POM shows merged configurations. In this case, it happens to be the same as the first example. However, had `testset_A` introduced configuration XML elements that already exist in `env_local`, they would have been appended:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration combine.children="append">
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <arquillian.launch>jbossas-managed-jenkins</arquillian.launch>
            <jbossHttpPortOverride>${jboss.http.port}</jbossHttpPortOverride>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <includes>
            <include>TestA1.java</include>
            <include>TestA2.java</include>
            <include>TestA3.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration combine.children="append">
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <arquillian.launch>jbossas-managed-jenkins</arquillian.launch>
        <jbossHttpPortOverride>${jboss.http.port}</jbossHttpPortOverride>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
      <includes>
        <include>TestA1.java</include>
        <include>TestA2.java</include>
        <include>TestA3.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```