# Update war name based on activated maven profile

Tags: java, maven, war

In my pom, I have two profiles.

1. test1
2. test2

Now I want my war name to change based on the activated profile.

### Expected Result

When `test1` profile is activated, war name should be `prefix-test1.war`.
When `test1` and `test2` are activated, war name should be `prefix-test1-test2.war`.
When **no** profile is activated, war name should be `prefix.war`.

My POM file ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.sbill</groupId>
      <artifactId>sbill-wrapper</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <artifactId>executable</artifactId>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>test1</id>
         <properties>
            <rp.build.warname>test1</rp.build.warname>
         </properties>
      </profile>
      <profile>
         <id>test2</id>
         <properties>
            <rp.build.warname>test2</rp.build.warname>
         </properties>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
   <build>
      <finalName>prefix-${rp.build.warname}</finalName>
   </build>
</project>
```

Right now if I run command `mvn clean install` the war name is `prefix-null.war` 
. If I run command `mvn clean install -P test1,test2` the war name is `prefix-test2.war`.

The result is different to what expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to avoid showing null when no profiles, we can provide a default value for the property `rp.build.warname`, as mentioned in [Setting default values for custom Maven 2 properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899274/setting-default-values-for-custom-maven-2-properties).

For the case running `mvn clean install -P test1,test2`, the war name is `prefix-test2.war` as the value of `rp.build.warname` is overridden, you may read [How are conflicting properties resolved if multiple profiles are activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477562/how-are-conflicting-properties-resolved-if-multiple-profiles-are-activated) for more details.
In Order to have multiple values, we can use two properties(`rp.build.warname1`, `rp.build.warname2`) instead.

The following pom.xml includes the above changes

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sbill</groupId>
        <artifactId>sbill-wrapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>executable</artifactId>

    <!-- Provide default value here to avoid null in file name -->
    <properties>
        <rp.build.warname1/>
        <rp.build.warname2/>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test1</id>
            <properties>
                <rp.build.warname1>-test1</rp.build.warname1>
            </properties>

        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>test2</id>
            <properties>
                <rp.build.warname2>-test2</rp.build.warname2>
            </properties>

        </profile>
    </profiles>   
    <build>
        <finalName>prefix${rp.build.warname1}${rp.build.warname2}</finalName>        
    </build> 

</project>
```

Comment: The “Setting default values for custom Maven 2 properties” link seems to be non-functional. Probably meant to go to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899274/setting-default-values-for-custom-maven-2-properties

Comment: @AliceM. good spot. I updated the link.